# Windows 7 vs Windows Server 2008 R2 performance for MySql server

Tags: mysql, windows-7, performance, windows-server-2008-r2

We are going to setup a new system for our MySql server (v5.1.58) and currently we are choosing between Windows 7 x64 Ultimate and Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.
Do you think we may get any performance increase if using Windows Server 2008 R2 (comparing to Windows 7)?

Comment: (You're Doing It Wrong)™  The right way to do this on the cheap is to use Linux and MySQL.

Comment: Did I ask for a cheap solution? Or did I specify that we are considering Linux also? We can afford $1000 for Windows Server, I just wanna know if it gives us any performance increase. And we need a Windows operating system because a couple of other Windows server-side applications will run there.

Comment: If you can afford a server OS, use a server OS.  I wouldn't use a horse to pull a trailer if I could afford a SUV.  Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: *Did I ask for a cheap solution?* - well actually by asking about using a desktop OS in a server role, you kinda sorta hinted that you either wanted to do it on the cheap or, at least, that you are very confused about operating systems. I'd certainly do it Tom's way rather than run a server platform on a desktop OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, Win7 is a client and 2008r2 is a server.  While they share the same code base, I'm pretty sure I'd stick with the server.  It's what it was designed for after all.

If you're worried about upfront cost, you have to figure that Server was designed with system tuning and client connections in mind.  Win7 isn't.  You'll be better suited in the long run paying the cost now instead of pulling your hair out later because you cheaped out in the front end.

Comment: I totally agree, it's like doing a server with a laptop. Laptop never been design for run server, so ...